# Obtain Data from two parse classes based on column in one table

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have to Parse Classes in my data browser, 'Details' and 'Content'. The 'Details' class has the following --> 'objectId', 'uuid' and 'proximity'. The 'Content' class has 'objectId', 'descId' and 'offer'.

I have created a web UI using the Javascript SDK so when the user enters the uuid, proximity and offer, uuid and proximity get stored in the 'Details' class, on success I then get the objectId of the newly created object. I then store that objectId in the 'Content' class under descId and the offer that was inputted by the user.

My problem is I have a html table that I need to populate, so I need to pull the data from both classes. The uuid and proximity from 'Details' and the offer from 'Content' so I need to do this in one query. This is my reason for storing the 'Details' objectId in the 'Content' class as a type of foreign key.

I am stuck at this cross roads and have tried include etc but I am just trying things and I'm not sure what I need to do. If anyone can help, perhaps show me a sample, I'd greatly appreciate it

Here is my js save code:

```
 //Creating Beacon Content Parse Object
    var iBeaconContent = Parse.Object.extend("Content");
    var beaconContent = new iBeaconContent();

    //Creating Object to save to iBeacon Description Table
    var iBeaconDescription = Parse.Object.extend("Details");
    var beaconDescription = new iBeaconDescription();

    beaconDescription.set("uuid", tdUuid.children("input[type=text]").val().toString());
    beaconDescription.set("proximity", parseInt(tdProximity.children($('prox')).val().toString()));

    beaconDescription.save(null, {
        success: function(beaconDescriptionObject) {
            var query = new Parse.Query("Details");
            query.equalTo("uuid", tdUuid.children("input[type=text]").val().toString());
            query.find({
                success: function(results) {

                    objectId = results[0].id;

                    beaconContent.set("descId", objectId);
                    beaconContent.set("offer", tdOffer.children("input[type=text]").val().toString());
                    beaconContent.save(null, {
                        success: function(object) {
                            document.location.reload(true);
                        }, error: function(beaconContent, error) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    });
```

***NEW JAVASCRIPT***

```
var BeaconDetail = Parse.Object.extend("Details");
var BeaconContent = Parse.Object.extend("Content");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(BeaconDetail);
innerQuery.exists("descId");
var query = Parse.Query(BeaconDetail);

query.matchesQuery("objectId", innerQuery);
    query.find({
        success:function(beaconContent){
            alert("Success----lenght:  " + beaconContent.length);

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you need to use a compound query or relationship query. Here are some links

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#compound-queries

https://parse.com/questions/compound-relational-queries

An example of a query from two classes is as follows

It would also be good to see the code, would help give a more relative answer.

CODE

```
var lotsOfWins = new Parse.Query("Player");
lotsOfWins.greaterThan("wins", 150);
 
var fewWins = new Parse.Query("Player");
fewWins.lessThan("wins", 5);
 
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(lotsOfWins, fewWins);
mainQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {
     // results contains a list of players that either have won a lot of games or won only a few games.
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // There was an error.
  }
});
```

Comment: Is that two queries on the same class?  "Player"?

Comment: yes, so you can have either a lessThan or greaterThan result in var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(lotsOfWins, fewWins)

Comment: I have two classes, so I'm assuming I need something like this here what I'm working on?     var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
var Comment = Parse.Object.extend("Comment");
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Post);
innerQuery.exists("image");
var query = new Parse.Query(Comment);
query.matchesQuery("post", innerQuery);
query.find({
  success: function(comments) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
  }
});  However, I'm unsure how to pass in the object id int the matches query

Comment: I think so, as far as I understand this is how to get results from different classes or to build multiple query results into one. I'm working on a similar line, still not fully got it working but from what I've learnt this is the approach to consider.

Comment: I've just added code to my original post, can you check it out and see how it works?  Do you know how to add the objectid to a matches query?

Comment: Let me try and get mine working and I'll share that with you.

Comment: Is there anyone that has any ideas on this?  I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Maybe also take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709131/simple-way-to-get-multiple-related-objects-in-parse-com-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks but that uses relation objects which I have tried and was unable to populate.  I just can't believe that there isn't something like a join query in parse

Comment: My issue has been resolved, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870300/why-does-this-query-return-all-query-results-and-not-just-those-matched-with-use/23912394?noredirect=1#comment36823872_23912394 still not sure if this helps, but it joins 2 separate classes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your `Content` class contains a pointer to your `Details` class in the `descId` property, and you want to be able to query based on some `Details` fields and return both objects?

NOTE: I must point out that `descId` is a very poorly named property that will just cause confusion. If it is a pointer, just give it a name like `desc`, leave off the `Id` suffix.

Anyway, if that is what you want:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Content");
var uuid = tdUuid.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();
var proximity = parseInt(tdProximity.children($('prox')).val().toString());
// consider logging those two variable to confirm they're what you want

// query properties of a pointer
query.equalTo("descId.uuid", uuid);
query.equalTo("descId.proximity", proximity);

// include the pointer in the output
query.include("descId");

query.find({
    success: function(beaconContent) {
        alert("Success -- length: " + beaconContent.length);
        // sample output of first result:
        var content = beaconContent[0];
        var detail = content.get("descId");
        console.log("uuid", detail.get("uuid"));
        console.log("proximity", detail.get("proximity"));
        console.log("offer", content.get("offer"));
    }
});
```